# How can Cassandra have no single point of failure when it has no master and data is not replicated but distributed?

Tags: cassandra

Perhaps I am misunderstanding, but the Apache Cassandra Wikipedia article says:

"Every node in the cluster has the same role. There is no single point of failure. Data is distributed across the cluster (so each node contains different data), but there is no master as every node can service any request."

How can each node contain different data, but there be no single point of failure? For instance, I would imagine that in this senario, if a node when down containing the record I was querying, then a different node would pickup that request, however, it would not have the data to satisfy it..since that data was on the node that went down..

Can someone clear this up for me?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, the data is (or at least, can be) replicated: http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/cluster_architecture/replication

Comment: So, say you have 10 nodes, and configure Cassandra to replicate your row across three of them. It's replicated. Two of the nodes with your row can be down, and you can still fetch it from the third.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Cassandra clusters *do* replicate data across the nodes. The specific number of replicas is configurable, but generally production clusters will use a replication factor of 3. This means that a given row will be stored on three different machines in the cluster. See the [reference documentation on replication](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/cluster_architecture/replication) for more details.

In terms of servicing requests, if a node receives a request for data that it does not have it will forward that request to the nodes that do own the data.

Comment: Ah, I see, that is very helpful. So if I had 10 nodes, and a replication factor of 10, then all my data would essentially be fully replicated. Not that this would be a good idea, but I would have to lose all 10 nodes to lose availability. Thanks!